# zsh cant find ionic init

Tags: ionic-framework, zsh

When trying to initiate ionic zsh can't find the command

```
zsh: command not found: ionic
```

I've tried to source ~/.bash_profile

```
$ echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/uberuser/.npm-global/bin:~/.npm-global/bin:~/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin
```

But sourcing didn't help.

Comment: You should update your path in `.zprofile`; `,bash_profile` is for `bash`. The question is, where is `ionic` located? It's your responsibility to know where it was installed so that you can update your `PATH` appropriately.

Comment: Ionic is located at `/usr/local/Cellar/node/13.6.0/bin/` how would I change PATH then? Could you give an example? @chepner

Comment: You add that path to the value of `PATH`.